# Change Matlab methods attributes

Tags: matlab, methods, attributes, metaclass

I am trying to create a Matlab Class, where the methods attributes are changed in the Class Constructor. The purpose of this is to hide / make visible some methods, depending on the class input.

For example:

```
classdef  (HandleCompatible) myClass < dynamicprops & handle % & hgsetget
properties (Hidden)
    myProp
end
methods (Hidden)
    function obj = myClass(input)
        %class constructor
        %add some dynamic properties
        switch input
            case 1
                %unknown code:
                %make myMethod1 visible
            case 2

                %unknown code:
                %make myMethod2 visible
            otherwise
                %unknown code:
                %make myMethod1 visible
                %make myMethod2 visible
        end
    end
end

methods (Hidden)
    function myMethod1 (obj, input)
        %function...
    end
    function output = myMethod2(obj, input)
        %function...
    end
end
end
```

I tried to use the following:

```
mco = metaclass(obj);
mlist = mco.MethodList;
mlist(myMethod1Index).Hidden = false;
```

, but I get the following error:

> Setting the 'Hidden' property of the 'meta.method' class is not allowed.

---

Thank you for your reply.

This could be a solution, if I need to access my methods selectively in the class constructor. Though, I need to use these methods in my program, and to have them visible or not, at tab completion:

```
%Obj1
myObj1 = myClass (inputs, '-1');
myObj1.myMethod1(arg);
%myObj1.myMethod2 - hidden


%Obj2
myObj2 = myClass (inputs, '1');
%myObj2.myMethod1 - hidden
value1 = myObj2.myMethod2(arg);


%Obj3
myObj3 = myClass (inputs, '0');
myObj3.myMethod1(arg);
value2 = myObj3.myMethod2(arg); 
%here i want to be able to access both methods
```

Maybe it is possible to select the method properties, during class constructor, and change the attributes. But this has to be done without using the metaclass

Answer (score 1):

Why not expose only a factory method and build instances of different classes depending on the input? You can use access qualifiers to lock things down like so:

```
% a.m
classdef a
    properties, a_thing, end
    methods ( Access = ?factory )
        function obj = a()
        end
    end
end

% b.m
classdef b
    properties, b_thing, end
    methods ( Access = ?factory )
        function obj = b()
        end
    end
end

% factory.m
classdef factory
    methods ( Static )
        function val = build(arg)
            if isequal(arg, 'a')
                val = a;
            else
                val = b;
            end
        end
    end
 end
```